# How to use SQLAlchemy hybrid_method and hybrid_property

Tags: python-2.7, sqlalchemy

I have read various SO answers, read the SQLA docs, googled, and asked Google Bard. But I still have found it difficult to understand exactly how SQLAlchemy's `hybrid_method` and `hybrid_property` work. How do I use them correctly, and what are the differences (if any) between them? I'm running `SQLAlchemy 1.0.9` and `Python 2.7`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Disclaimer:

After banging my head against this for a couple of weeks, I got things to work as needed. I wanted to provide info to help others (and my future self). However, I couldn't use my actual code so I've made up some scenarios in the below answer. Full disclouse -- I didn't setup and run the examples, but they should be sufficient to get the gist of things. Please feel free to comment any suggestions/changes I should make to improve this answer. Thanks!

### Documentation:

- [SQLA docs on hybrid attributes](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/extensions/hybrid.html)
- [SQLA docs on hybrid_method](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/extensions/hybrid.html#sqlalchemy.ext.hybrid.hybrid_method)
- [SQLA docs on hybrid_property](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/extensions/hybrid.html#sqlalchemy.ext.hybrid.hybrid_property)

### Answer:

SQLAlchemy has a couple of nifty things, called `hybrid_method` and `hybrid_property`. These are essentially properties/methods on a SQLAlchemy class, which can be used in a query statement. The kicker is that they can be functions and DO stuff; for example, you could do:

```py
class Address():
    ...

class User():
    first_name = Column(String)
    last_name = Column(String)
    num_orders = Column(Integer, nullable=True)
    orders = relationship('Orders')

    @hybrid_property
    def full_name(self):
            return self.first_name + ' ' + self.last_name

result = session.query(User).filter(User.full_name == 'john doe').first()
```

Now, the above is a fairly contrived example. In reality, you will probably want to do more complex things. Here is another example:

```py
class OrderStatusEnum(enum.Enum):
        REJECTED = 'rejected'
        CANCELED = 'canceled'

class Orders
    status = Column(String)
    user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('users.id'), nullable=False)
    order_count = Column(Integer)
    ...

    @hybrid_property
    def status_int(self):
      for cancel_status in OrderStatusEnum:
          if self.status == cancel_status.value:
              return 0
      else:
          return 1
    
    @status_int.expression
    def status_int(cls):
        return case([
            (cls.status == OrderStatusEnum.REJECTED.value, 0),
            (cls.status == OrderStatusEnum.CANCELED.value, 0),
        ], else_=1)

# QUERY
result = session.query(func.avg(Orders.status_int)).group_by(Orders.id).all()
```

You’ll notice in the above that there are now *two* functions called `status_int`. This is because SQLAlchemy needs one to evaluate in Python and one to evaluate in SQL. Here’s the difference:

```py
# == Example 1 ==
order = session.query(Order).get(<id>)
order.status_int # --> has access to the specific instance, and will run the python method

# == Example 2 ==
result = session.query(func.avg(Orders.status_int)).group_by(Orders.id).all()
# runs the SQL Expression, because it does not have access to specific instances
```

`hybrid_property` and `hybrid_method` functions allow for the definition of a SQL Expression. This is done by defining the function a second time, but with a decorator that shares the name of the original function (see below). Additionally, it’s **important** to know that **the python method and SQL expression should be functionally equivalent**. This seems logical, but it’s worth highlighting.

```py
@hybrid_property
def status_int(self)
        ... # python method

@status_int.expression
def status_int(self)
        ... # SQL expression
```

The `hybrid_method` is generally very similar, but there are a couple of “gotchas” to be aware of.

1. `hybrid_method` has class access, not instance access. So don’t expect to be able to refer to specific instance column value.
2. `hybrid_method.expression` function is defined using `cls`, not `self` — again, because it has class access not instance access (it’s basically a class method).

```py
class Orders
    ...

    @hybrid_method
    def status_for_user(self, user):
            res = session.query(Orders.order_count).filter(Orders.user_id == user.id).first()
            if res > 0:
                    return 'active'
            elif res == 0:
                    return 'registered'
            else:
                    return 'inactive'

    @status_for_user.expression
    def status_for_user(cls, user):
            query = session.query(Orders.order_count).filter(Orders.user_id == user.id).first()

            return case([
                    (literal(query) > 0, 'active'),
                    (literal(query) == 0, 'registered')
            ], else_='inactive')

user = session.query(User).get(1)
result = session.query(User, Orders.id).join(Orders, Orders.user_id == User.id).filter(Orders.status_for_user(user) == 'active').all()
```

Hopefully this explanation with examples is helpful to others in the future. If I missed anything important, and/or there is an error, please let me know and I am happy to update.

Comment: Thanks, this helped a lot. Do you by a chance have links to examples on how to return SQL using func method? For example I have

Comment: ,I would like to return cls.last+ ', ' + cls.first + ' ' + cls.middle to be 'Doe, John Frankie'. I'm using return func.lower(cls.last)+ ', ' +  func.lower(cls.first) + ' ' +  func.lower(cls.middle), but I do not know if this is the right way to generate SQL. Can I just return the string without using the func? Thanks